# REGEX if string is present then select the last character on the line

Tags: regex, pcre

I am using PCRE.

I need help developing a REGEX to select the end of the last character at the line. In my example below I am using a snippet from an XML file and I need the regex to find any lines that have 'target=' if it does then to select '>'

```
<wrapping target="CLIENT" source="INCD"/>
```

I have tried the regex below but I am only getting CLIENT" source="INCD"/
I need it to find > if target= exisit.

```
(?<=target=")(.*?)(?=>)
```

Comment: `target=.*?\K>` ? `target=[^\n]*\K[^\n]` ?

Comment: in which language will you use the regex? Not all regex flavours allow for variable width lookbehinds.

Comment: What do you want to do with that last character if you have selected it? Is it the last character on the whole line? Can it be any character,  or is the always the closing `>` ?

Comment: I am using PCRE. I was attempting with the answer giving below and I cannot use * for a lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal with `target=.+?".\K>`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/(?<=target=).*(.)$/gm
```

See demo on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Tq4nCF/1)

Comment: your last group is obsolete. This regex also works: `/(?<=target=.*?).$/gm`

Comment: Sorry i'm using PCRE so your answer are not currently working.

Comment: Regex updated. Tried with a group construct. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/6yGs2z/1) works for you:
`(?<=target=\".{1,255}).$`

The difficulty arrises from the limitation that lookbehinds require a fixed width in Java. The workaraound is to use a fixed width range (`{1,255}`) instead of a variable-width quantifier (`+`, `*`).

Answer (score 0):

As @jhnc shows in their comment to your question, if you are using PCRE, there is no need for using a lookbehind for this use case. Describe the line you want to match in an expression and then add the `\K` meta sequence right before the part that you want returned as a match. The regex engine will still match the whole expression but will drop all characters that were consumed previous to `\K` from the match it returns.

For example, `\btarget=.*\K.` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HK3oju/1)) if you want the last character on the same line as 'target=' or `\btarget=[^>\n]*\K>` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1eJLbJ/1)) if you want the closing '>' of the tag that contains target.

If you just want to move the match pointer and don't want anything returned, put the `\K` at the end of the expression. The engine will then match the position immediately after what your expression described: `\btarget=.*\K`

Comment: Thanks. I actually went with target=.+?".\K>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\K` to forget what has been matched until now, and then use `\S` to match the last single non whitespace character:

```
\btarget=.*\K\S
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LJ4hVb/1)

Comment: Thanks. I actually went with target=.+?".\K>

Answer (score 0):

To place the cursor after the *>* character, you can use the following.

```
(?:(?<=target=).+?)(?<=>).?
```